# TSQL - find previous row with value and update initial rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm working on a data migration (SQL Server 2012) and at one point in the script I have all of my rows like this (just showing the dataset for one customer ID, and truncating the date):

```
CustTxnID   CustomerID  TransDate   PmtActID
1964237     385120      10/2/2016   12820
1964529     385120      10/3/2016   NULL
2003082     385120      11/2/2016   NULL
2041647     385120      12/2/2016   NULL
2060535     385120      12/16/2016  10890
2060926     385120      12/17/2016  NULL
2081969     385120      1/2/2017    NULL
2128232     385120      2/2/2017    NULL
2173356     385120      3/2/2017    NULL
```

What I want to do is for every row that has a NULL PmtActID, update the PmtActID to match the value stored in the first row created before it that has a PmtActID value.  So for example, CustTxnID 1964529, 2003082 and 2041647 would be updated with PmtActID 12820, and the other rows with a null PmtActID would be updated to 10890.

A few notes that may help...  We know that the earliest transaction for the customer has a PmtActID value at this point.  We also know that the transactions are inserted in chronological order.

I've tried several ways that have resulted in the correct data, but not only have they performed poorly (the transaction table has about 4 million rows), they have felt "wrong".  I feel like there's a simple solution here that I'm overlooking.

One approach was to join to the txn table, then a subquery that collected all potential matches (rows with PmtActID whose TransDate < current row's TransDate, ordered by Max(CustTxnID) to find the closest)...   another was to sequence the rows with a pmtactid, and then for the null rows select with a count of the number of rows with pmtactid that preceded them (which would match the sequence)...  etc etc etc.  But quite simply, I strongly suspect I'm missing something simple, that would surely perform better than what I've been doing.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE** I tried this based on Gordon's reply:

```
SELECT
    T.CustomerID
    ,T.CustomerTransactionID
    ,T.TransDate
    ,T.PaymentAccountID
    ,first_value(T.PaymentAccountID) over (
        partition by CustomerID 
        order by 
            (case when PaymentAccountID is null then 1 else 2 end) desc,
            transdate desc ) AS new_pmtActId
FROM
    CustomerTransaction T 
WHERE
    T.CustomerID=385120
ORDER BY
    TransDate desc
```

(Note I used the full column names here instead of abbreviating) but using this, every row received 10890.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the previous value using `first_value()` and then use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             max(pmtActId) over (partition by CustomerID, transdate_notnull) as new_pmtActId
      from (select t.*,
                   max(case when pmtActId is not null then transdate end) over (partition by customerid order by transdate) as transdate_notnull
            from t
           ) t
     )
update toupdate
    set pmtActId = new_pmtActId
    where pmtActId is null;
```

Of course, test the CTE before doing the `update` to be sure the values are what you intend.

Standard SQL has a construct `lag()` with `ignore nulls`.  However, SQL Server does not implement it.

[Here](http://rextester.com/UCNXQ31019) is a rextester.

Comment: Had issues getting my comment to format correctly, so I updated my main post based on your reply.  Thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: @GA15859 . . . I fixed the answer.

Comment: Perfect, this worked very well!  Always the best type of answer - one that is both correct and that you learn from.  Thanks!